# Ubuntu Compatibility on the Lenovo B580 laptop

Tags: installation, compatibility

I'm planning to buy a new laptop and I would like to use Ubuntu as my OS. I've zoomed in on this Lenovo:

Model: B580
Specs:

Intel Core i5-3210M,(Dual-Core), 3 MB Cache 
4(+4) GB RAM, 
Intel HM77 Express Chipset,
Intel HD 4000 Graphic Card, 
1 TB hard-drive.

This laptop comes with Windows 8 pre-installed. I'd appreciate it if you let me know your experience if you've installed Ubuntu on such a configuration. Are there any problems?

Disclaimer: My knowledge of computer hardware/OS is limited. Jargon-free answers will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Did you Google around on `Lenovo B580 linux compatibility`? One of first hits point me to a web shop [selling this device](http://www.hettes.nl/product/laptops/Lenovo/lenovo_b580_m94a7mh_ubuntu_linux) with Ubuntu... so I guess it won't be too hard to get Ubuntu running.

Comment: I've seen the review of the B580 with Intel Celeron. That seems to work okay on Ubuntu. But is the Ubuntu experience likely to be any different with an i5 processor and Intel HD graphic card? I must point out that the B580 does not seem to have any fixed specs. Hence my question.

Comment: The i5 processor and Intel HD Graphics should be the least of your worries. These are very well supported, being one of the most mainstream products in regular desktop/mobile computers nowadays. Intel provides very good support for these components with very high quality open source drivers. Harder are the components like networking, Bluetooth, etc. These are very much different on the specific models within the same line of laptops.

Answer (score 0):

well im using lenovo B460 more than 2 years .. and still working like new for performance .. best booting until now .

Comment: B460 is not a B580.

Comment: Intel Core i3 (Dual-Core), 3 MB Cache   8GB RAM, Intel HM77 Express Chipset, Intel HD 4000 Graphic Card,320HDD  ..all same with mine. tell me what different other than brand name and series and hard disk and processor ?

Comment: A 3rd-gen Intel processor (Ivy Bridge) can't be used for 2 years now, as it's just introduced less than a year ago. Moreover, all other components besides this can be very very different. ACPI/BIOS/EFI interface, networking, sound card, etc. etc.

Comment: you need to explain it .. because i have lot of client that using ubuntu with pentium 3 with 1004lts. and they are ain't 3rd gen of intel .. so what are you trying to say ? im using 1204 lts with 64 bit .

Comment: 3rd Generation i3 (2012) is not Pentium III (1999). See [Intel ARK](http://ark.intel.com/) for a nice overview of their products.